# OutlineInputBorder flutter hasize issue

Tags: flutter, user-interface

When I add a border to the TextField i get an issue:

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPositionedBox#e1c8e relayoutBoundary=up34 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'

code down there:
[OutlineInputBorderIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si7ob.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `ListView` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` without setting a `height` for the `ListView`. Wrap the `ListView` inside a `SizedBox` and set a `height`.

There are other approaches that can be used as well, such as `Expanded`, for example. I suggest studying this widget, it will help you a lot.